# Getting total number of page using pdfinfo not showing result

Tags: php

I am using pdfinfo for getting total number of pages in a pdf file using php.

```
function getPDFNoOfPages($document) {

    $cmd = "C:/wamp/www/PhpProject1/pdfinfo.exe"; 

    exec("$cmd $document", $output);


    $pagecount = 0;
    foreach ($output as $op) {
        // Extract the number
        if (preg_match("/Pages:\s*(\d+)/i", $op, $matches) === 1) {
            $pagecount = intval($matches[1]);
            break;
        }
    }

    return $pagecount;
}


$document = 'test.pdf';   
echo getPDFNoOfPages($document);
```

here my pdf file is in

> C:/wamp/www/PhpProject1/test.pdf

but it showing output '0' .how to solve this.thanks in advance

Comment: try this path if using windows `$cmd = "C:\\wamp\\www\\PhpProject1\\pdfinfo.exe";`

Comment: yes i had tried but getting the same result,0

Comment: did you debug commend on `console` window? `cmd:> C:\wamp\www\PhpProject1\pdfinfo.exe C:\wamp\www\PhpProject1\test.pdf`

Comment: yes,when i am executing this command installation of pdfinfo starts again.